# Rolling mean without sorting descending time series

Tags: python, pandas, mean, rolling-computation

is there a way to calculate a rolling mean on a descending time series without sorting it into a ascending one?

Original time series with same timestamp order as in csv file.

```
pd.read_csv(data_dir+items+extension, parse_dates=True, index_col='timestamp').sort_index(ascending=False)

timestamp   open
2021-05-06  90.000
2021-05-05  93.600
2021-05-04  90.840
2021-05-03  91.700  
2021-04-30  91.355
```

Rolling mean

```
stock_dict[items]["SMA100"]=pd.Series(stock_dict[items]["close"]).rolling(window=100).mean()
```

ascending = False

```
    open    high    low close   volume  SMA100
timestamp                       
2021-05-06  90.000  93.5200 89.64   93.03   8024053 NaN
2021-05-05  93.600  94.7700 90.00   90.08   13079308    NaN
2021-05-04  90.840  90.9700 87.44   88.69   15147509    NaN
2021-05-03  91.700  92.0200 90.79   91.15   6641764 NaN
2021-04-30  91.355  91.9868 90.89   91.19   6614347 NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1999-11-05  14.560  15.5000 14.50   15.38   1308267 14.9245
1999-11-04  14.690  14.7500 14.25   14.62   207033  14.9395
1999-11-03  14.310  14.5000 14.12   14.50   61600   14.9526
1999-11-02  14.250  15.0000 14.16   14.25   128817  14.9639
1999-11-01  14.190  14.3800 13.94   14.06   173233  14.9682
```

ascending = True

```
open    high    low close   volume  SMA100
timestamp                       
1999-11-01  14.190  14.3800 13.94   14.06   173233  NaN
1999-11-02  14.250  15.0000 14.16   14.25   128817  NaN
1999-11-03  14.310  14.5000 14.12   14.50   61600   NaN
1999-11-04  14.690  14.7500 14.25   14.62   207033  NaN
1999-11-05  14.560  15.5000 14.50   15.38   1308267 NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-04-30  91.355  91.9868 90.89   91.19   6614347 93.1148
2021-05-03  91.700  92.0200 90.79   91.15   6641764 93.2036
2021-05-04  90.840  90.9700 87.44   88.69   15147509    93.2542
2021-05-05  93.600  94.7700 90.00   90.08   13079308    93.3292
2021-05-06  90.000  93.5200 89.64   93.03   8024053 93.4284
```

As time series goes from 1999 to 2012 rolling mean is correct in case of ascending = True.

So either I have to change sorting of data, which I would like to avoid, or I have somehow to tell rolling mean function to start with last entry and calculate backwards.

Comment: how does `ascending = True` help you calculate the moving average? Can you post the code that you have used to do this?

Comment: Added more details